# Unable to freeze the scroll after setting body.overflow to hidden in Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, next.js, frontend

I am having this issue in my Nextjs where I am unable to freeze the page from scrolling even after I set the `document.body.style.overflow` to `hidden`.

This is the code:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-leavitt-i0fz2c?file=%2Fpages%2Findex.tsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A28%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A13%2C%22startColumn%22%3A27%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A13%7D%5D

As you can see:
In lines 11-14 where I click the freeze button, it disables scrolling.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V5hU.png)

Result:
The page is still scrollable.

Please let me know the solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position:fixed` in addition to `overflow:hidden`

```js
document.body.style.cssText = "overflow: hidden; position:fixed;";
```

Preventing scrolling will lose the scroll position. So, when scrolling is reenabled, it will reset the scroll position to the top of the page instead of where the user left off. To prevent this, you need to set the scrollTop position.

```js
const scrollTop = (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop;
document.body.style.cssText = `overflow: hidden; position:fixed; margin-top: -${scrollTop}px;`; // add here to prevent shifting content on freeze
```

On unfreezing, set the scroll top value to the original scroll top value before the freeze. Store it in state or a variable so it can be used later.

```js
const scrollTop = (document.documentElement || document.body).scrollTop; // original value to store in state or variable before freezing.

//After unfreezing, set back to original value
document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me now. But when I unfreeze it, it goes back the top, how should I set it so it scroll back to where I freeze it?

Comment: I added a bit more detail at the end.

Answer (score 1):

By default NextJS has this in their globals.css file

```
html, body {
 max-width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Even when you apply overflow: hidden to your body, the parent container html still has overflow-x: hidden applied to it. Changing the styling in the globals.css to

```
html {
 max-width: 100vw;
}

body {
 max-width: 100vw;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

should get it working for you. What the above code does is merely remove the default overflow property from the html.